# Hive error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:47 missing : at 'array' near '<EOF>'

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to create array of structure within the structure.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST_EXTTBL_PAGE_VISIT_MASTER
(
    PERSONALIZATION_DATA STRUCT<EXPOSED_RULES array<struct<RULE_ID:varchar(70),RULESETID:varchar(70)>>>
)
COMMENT 'Page Visit details'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|'
map keys terminated by ':'
lines terminated by '\n'
LOCATION 's3a://XXX';
```

Please suggest what im missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `":"` after your array name

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TEST_EXTTBL_PAGE_VISIT_MASTER
(
    PERSONALIZATION_DATA STRUCT<EXPOSED_RULES: array<struct<RULE_ID:varchar(70),RULESETID:varchar(70)>>>
)
COMMENT 'Page Visit details'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|'
map keys terminated by ':'
lines terminated by '\n'
LOCATION 's3a://XXX';
```